# Acceder a variables de entorno en mac

Tags: nodejs, express, macos, virtualenv

venia desarrollando una API con node.js y express.js en windows 10 y utilizaba un archivo .env para colocar las variables de entorno como la url de la base de datos y otras variables.
El problema que tengo es que quiero trabajar con la misma API en Mac y no puede leer el archivo .env, cuando intento acceder a alguna variable del archivo, como por ejemplo así:

```
const connectionString = process.env.MONGO_DB_SRV
```

Al imprimir en consola `connectionString` imprime `undefined`, MacOs debe tener otra forma de crear variables de entorno, como podría hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Usas [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)? Indica tu versión de macOS.

Comment: Si, esta instalado, es MacOs monterey, ya encontré el problema, en MacOs no se puede simplemente copiar y pegar un archivo .env por que estos estan ocultos por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

En MacOs los archivos que comienzan con un "." como por ejemplo .env estan reservados para el sistema por lo cual al traer transferir un archivo .env desde windows a MacOs se le añade automaticamente un nombre antes del "." por lo que dotenv no lo detecta, para lograr crearlo hay que usar `touch .env` desde la terminal para crear el archivo y abrirlo con un editor para poder escribir sobre el, asi lo solucioné.